# apt-get update for ubuntu 10.04

Tags: updates, 10.04, update-alternatives

I know that Ubuntu 10.04 is no longer supported.

But I am still using it, becuase I use virtual machine (VirtualBox), and on previous trials to use any more updated Ubuntu version was too heavy, and slow, in my machine.

Now, when I try doing:

```
apt-get update
```

I receive a bunch of errors:

```
...
Ign http://il.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/multiverse Packages
Ign http://il.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/multiverse Sources
Err http://il.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/main Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://il.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/restricted Packages
  404  Not Found
...
Err http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/main Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
...
W: Failed to fetch     http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
```

I am sure I used to do that in the past without any issues.

Is it because Ubuntu 10.04 was removed from these repositories, or is it some other issue?

Comment: if you not it is end of life ... why bother asking?

Comment: have you tried a more lightweight Ubuntu flavour? Xubuntu, Lubuntu, or, as I understand, MATE?

Comment: deleted my answer because I misread the question

Comment: I just had this problem in an old VM I've inherited.  I added the old-releases.ubuntu.com URLs as seen at https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/issues/1902, to /etc/apt/sources.list.  This was enough to update/install new packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's really trivial to verify, just browse to http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ (you can also drop the`il` from the front) and check the results.

The site is responding, you get a connection, but there is no `lucid` among the directories corresponding to Ubuntu releases.

Conclusion: the packages were removed.

Answer (score 23):

To complement techraf's answer, if you want to use old releases, you can access them using this address:

`http://old-releases.ubuntu.com`

To enable this, open the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with a text editor, and wherever you see `archive.ubuntu.com` (the source of releases actively supported), change it to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` (you can use the find & replace option to speed it up).

Comment: I tried this but still apt-get update or upgrade is not working. I am using ubuntu 10

Comment: worked relatively well for me, i had to replace us.archive with old-releases, and also 'security.ubuntu.com' with 'old-release.ubuntu.com'